# executing sql command from vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

This is my code in `VB.Net`. I am doing connectivity from `vb10` to oracle 10g. Ghe problem is my code is working fine in `sql prompt` as

```
SQL> insert into product values(pid_inc(),'name',' desc ',101,'"c:\imgloc','brand ',1,10)
```

but when I try to access it from vb it stops working. Why is that?
My vb code is:

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=jon;password=snow;Data Source=KAUSTUBH-PC;Persist Security Info=False")
con.Open()
name = TextBox1.Text
desc = TextBox2.Text
price = Val(TextBox3.Text)
available = Val(TextBox4.Text)
brand = TextBox5.Text
cat = ComboBox1.Text

If (name <> "") Then
    nameflg = True
Else
    nameflg = False
    MsgBox(" product name cannot be empty")
End If

If (available > 0) Then
    availableflg = True
Else
    availableflg = False
    MsgBox("quantity cannot be 0")
End If

If (brand <> "") Then
    brandflg = True
Else
    brandflg = False
    MsgBox(" insert brand name")
End If

If (cat <> "") Then
    catflg = True
Else
    catflg = False
    MsgBox("pleaese select categoty")
End If
If (nameflg And logoflg And brandflg And catflg And availableflg) Then
    query = "Select cat_id from category where cat_name='" + cat + "'"
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, con)
    x = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString
    cat_id = Val(x)
    query = "insert into product values(pid_inc(),'" & name & "','" & desc & "'," & price & ",'" & imgloc & "','" & brand & "'," & cat_id & "," & available & ")"
    Dim cmd1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, con)
    cat_id = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If (cat_id = 0) Then
        MsgBox("Record not inserted properly ....try again")
    Else
        MsgBox("Record inserted successfully")
    End If
'Else
'   MsgBox("please fill the fields properly")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `... it stops working` Please, tell us what exactly doesn't work as expected? Post any error messages, line at which execution stops, expected and actual behaviour.

Comment: it doesnt give any error. where as the VB form goes not responding state or some time in stuck as it is till i stop the project. actually i tried the

Comment: You should *never* use string concatenation to build a SQL statement from user-provided parameters. Apart from trashing the shared pool, this is an invitation to SQL injection attacks. Please use prepared statements instead (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/connector-net-programming-prepared.html )

Comment: `imgloc` is not defined